# APIkit API Console returns json example instead of real response

Tags: mule, cloudhub, apikit

Developing Mule API and need to deploy to cloudhub and set up an API Console to test the endpoints. Everything is fine except for the responses - API Console returns JSON example response instead of real responses, got from processing real data. In this state, API Console is worthless.

APIkit Router configuration:

```
<apikit:config name="api-config" raml="api.raml"
    consoleEnabled="true" doc:name="Router" consolePath="console"
    keepRamlBaseUri="true" />
```

Note: generating RESTful flows from api.raml, does not produce api-console flow

Comment: Which versions of Mule an apikit are used?

Comment: @AlejandroDobniewski Mule - 3.9.2, not sure about the apikit version as I don't have the laptop I worked on anymore. I believe it was the latest apikit version